# Override CustomerFormatter.php for birthday form

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I would like to put the birthday field mandatory, so I override the CustomerFormatter but it does not work at all. That's how I did:

```
<?php

class CustomerFormatter extends CustomerFormatterCore
{
    public function getFormat()
    {
        $customerForm = parent::getFormat();

        if ($customerForm->ask_for_birthdate) {
            $format['birthday'] = (new FormField)
                ->setName('birthday')
                ->setType('text')
                ->setLabel(
                    $customerForm->translator->trans(
                        'Birthdate', [], 'Shop.Forms.Labels'
                    )
                )
                ->addAvailableValue('placeholder', Tools::getDateFormat())
                ->addAvailableValue(
                    'comment',
                    $customerForm->translator->trans('(E.g.: %date_format%)', array('%date_format%' => Tools::formatDateStr('31 May 1970')), 'Shop.Forms.Help')
                )
                ->setRequired(true)
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

I am under Prestashop 1.7.3.3

Do you have an idea of ​​the problem ? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Probably to late for you but it might help others, this is unfortunately impossible with 1.7.

"Yes, overrides work as usual on all classes that have no namespace (so you can still override Product, Address, etc.)."

http://build.prestashop.com/news/prestashop-1-7-faq/#can-developers-still-use-overrides-in-17

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to public_html/override/classes/form/ and create the file CustomerFormatter.php then type this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Override CustomerFormatter
 */

use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class CustomerFormatter extends CustomerFormatterCore
{

    private $translator;
    private $language;

    private $ask_for_birthdate = true;
    private $ask_for_password = true;
    private $password_is_required = true;
    private $ask_for_new_password = false;

    public function __construct(
        TranslatorInterface $translator,
        Language $language
    ) {
        parent::__construct($translator, $language);
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->language = $language;
    }

    public function getFormat()
    {
        $format = parent::getFormat();

        $format = [];

        if ($this->ask_for_birthdate) {
            $format['birthday'] = (new FormField())
                ->setName('birthday')
                ->setType('birthday')
                ->setLabel(
                    $this->translator->trans(
                        'Birthdate',
                        [],
                        'Shop.Forms.Labels'
                    )
                )
                ->setRequired($this->password_is_required);
        }
    }
```

You need to use:

```
->setRequired($this->password_is_required)
```

Because there's an error on checkout for guests purchases. So like this, it would be an optional field.